# Keras Dense Neural Net Predicting in Narrow Range

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've been playing with Numer.ai data, mostly as a way to improve my understanding of neural nets but I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to get past. No matter the configuration of my dense neural net, the output comes out in a tight range.
The input is 300 scaled feature columns (0 to 1) and the target is between 0 and 1 (values of 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1)

Here is my fully reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
# load data
training_data = pd.read_csv("https://numerai-public-datasets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest_numerai_training_data.csv.xz")
tournament_data = pd.read_csv("https://numerai-public-datasets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest_numerai_tournament_data.csv.xz")

feature_cols = training_data.columns[training_data.columns.str.startswith('feature')]
# select those columns out of the training dataset
X_train = training_data[feature_cols].to_numpy()
# select target variables
y_train = training_data.loc[:,'target'].to_numpy()

#same thing on validation data
val_data = tournament_data[tournament_data.data_type=='validation']
X_val = val_data[feature_cols]
y_val= val_data.loc[:,'target']
```

I've tried a number of different configurations in my neural network (different optimizers: adam and sgd, different learning rates 0.01 down to 0.0001, different neuron sizes, adding dropout: although, I didn't expect this to work because it seems to be a problem with bias, not variance, using linear, softmax, and sigmoid final layer activation functions: softmax produces negative values so that was an immediate non-starter, different batch sizes: as small as 16 and as large as 256, adding or removing batch normalization, shuffling the input data, and training for different numbers of epochs). Ultimately, the results are one of two things:

1. Predicted values are all the same number, usually somewhere in the 0.45 to 0.55 area
2. Predicted values are in a very narrow range, usually not more than 0.05 different. So the values are 0.45 to 0.55

I can't figure out what configuration changes I need to make to get this neural network to output predictions across a broader area of the 0 to 1 range.

```
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

dropout_rate = 0.15

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1028, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
  loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=200,
          verbose=1)

# Prediction output
predictions_df = model.predict(X_val)
predictions_df = predictions_df.reshape(len(predictions_df))

pred_max = predictions_df.max()
pred_min = predictions_df.min()
pred_range = pred_max - pred_min

print(pred_max, pred_min, pred_range)
# example output: 0.51895267 0.47968164 0.039271027
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

There is an impact on them when the following changes are made (tests run on batches size of 512, number of epochs 5, below results are only on training data) -

1. Loss set to `mse` instead of `binary_crossentropy`
2. Batch size 512 (for quick prototyping)
3. Epochs set to 5 (loss flattens after that)
4. Remove l2 regularization, and increase dropout
5. Set output activation -

- With `sigmoid` -> Max:0.60, ​Min: 0.36
- Without activation -> Max: 0.69, Min: 0.29
- With `relu` -> Max: 0.73,  Min: 0.10

Here is the code for testing purposes -

```
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

dropout_rate = 0.50

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
  loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          #validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          batch_size=512,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1)

# Prediction output
predictions_df = model.predict(X_train)
predictions_df = predictions_df.reshape(len(predictions_df))

pred_max = predictions_df.max()
pred_min = predictions_df.min()
pred_range = pred_max - pred_min

print(pred_max, pred_min, pred_range)
```

```
0.73566914 0.1063129 0.62935627
```

---

#### Proposed solutions

You are trying to solve a regression problem of predicting an arbitrary value between 0 to 1 `(values of 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1)`, but trying to solve it as a binary classification problem using a `sigmoid` activation and a `binary_crossentropy` loss.

What you may want to try is using `mse` and/or removing any output activation (or better, use `relu` as suggested by @desertnaut). You could simply be underfitting as suggested by @xdurch0. Try with and without the regularization as well.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1028, activation = 'relu')
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Check this table to help you with how to use losses and activations for different types of problem settings.

[image]

On a side note, the discrete nature of the values in your dependent variable, y, you can also consider reframing the problem as a multi-class single-label classification problem, if the downstream task allows it.

Comment: The table you posted doesn't match the answer. According to my understanding, OP is doing "regression to values between 0 and 1", where your table proposes sigmoid activation and _either_ mse or binary cross-entropy. I would assume that OP's model is simply underfitting, but the question doesn't provide any detail on what the task is etc., so it's hard to say anything more concrete either way.

Comment: That could of course be a reason, but as I mention, some variations in the loss function and output layer activation may be required, if that is not the case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for the possibility of underfitting.

Comment: OP's  code is fully reproducible; one could easily check that the proposed solution does not offer any improvement (plus that you should arguably advise to also add a `relu` activation in the first layer).

Comment: Your `relu` suggestion is on point, however, the claim "doesn't not offer any improvement" is false. I have tested the different activations and shown that it does have impact. Please see my edited results for reproducible code to test yourselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there are a couple problems. In your edited response, you mention using mae but the code you pasted uses mse. You also didn't mention increasing the dropout rate. However, when I run your code with the validation data added back in, I'm seeing the same results mentioned before.

Comment: When looking into it more, I am still only seeing predictions in the 0.55 to 0.44 range when predicting on the training set using the code above.

Comment: Oh apologies, I think I wanted to mention MSE. I'll edit that. Secondly, I increase dropout to account for the removing regularization to improve model generalization. I'll look into the validation part of it, but the point I wanted to prove was that the loss and the output activation do have an impact on the range, atleast while training.

Comment: Will spend some more time on the model and share my findings accordingly.